# How to run a web page like it is an app?

Tags: windows, windows-10, firefox, browser

I am using Windows 10 and I have 3 web pages I switch between frequently for work as well as 3 or so applications.

I use the key combination ALT + TAB to switch between apps. But when I want apps are web pages ALT + TAB does not switch between them. Instead, I have to switch to my browser and then click the tab. If I have multiple browser windows open I have to find the browser window that has my tabs and then click on the tabs.

Is there a way to make a web page appear as an Application to Windows so that ALT + TAB we switch between it.

**EDIT:**
I'm an idiot. If I pull the tab out into it's own window I can tab through it along with other applicatins. I'll keep this up bc I like the answer provided.

**EDIT 2:**
Not a complete idiot. I forgot about when I'm using a mouse. Windows groups applications along the task bar. So if I'm using a browser with 10 windows all windows are under that one icon. I would have to click the browser icon and then click again after I found the window (with tab I'm looking for in it). If I had a separate application it would appear by itself in the task bar. The answer by @heavyd fixes this (not sure it works with Firefox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chrome you can use Menu -> More Tools -> Add to desktop.  This will prompt you for a name and allow you to select the "Open as window" option.  With that option selected, you can then use the shortcut on your desktop or Start Menu to open that site in a new window.

[image: Screenshot]

This process will also add the application to Chrome's built in App launcher, so if you don't like the desktop/start menu shortcut, you can just use the icon in Chrome's App Launcher.

Answer (score 1):

You can also easily Ctrl + tab between tabs in most web browsers across OSs (Mac uses command I believe instead of control for this I believe)